# The dual of the Banach space $C(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

It is well-known that the dual of the Banach space $C([0,1])$, i.e. the space of all continuous functions on the interval, is the space of all functions of bounded variation on the interval, $BV([0,1])$.  If $\Omega$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, What is the dual of $C(\Omega)$?  How about the dual of all *absolutely continuous* functions on $\Omega$, $AC(\Omega)$?  What do the inner products look like?

Comment: The abstraction of integration with respect to a function of bounded variation is integration with respect to a measure. The more general space has dual consisting of complex Borel meausures (the sigma algebra generated by the open sets = Borel subsets.) What norm to do you want to use on the absolutely continuous functions on $[0,1]$?